# Difference between empirical naive bayes & parametric bayes classifiers

Tags: data-mining, bayesian

Im trying to understand the difference between each of these.

What is the difference between empirical naive bayes classifiers and parametric bayes classifiers?

Answer (score 1):

The *emperical* part means that the distribution is estimated from the data, rather than being fixed before analysis begins

> Empirical Bayes methods are procedures for statistical inference in which the prior distribution is estimated from the data. This approach stands in contrast to standard Bayesian methods, for which the prior distribution is fixed before any data are observed. Despite this difference in perspective, empirical Bayes may be viewed as an approximation to a fully Bayesian treatment of a hierarchical model wherein the parameters at the highest level of the hierarchy are set to their most likely values, instead of being integrated out. Empirical Bayes, also known as maximum marginal likelihood,[1] represents one approach for setting hyperparameters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method

*Naive* means that the value of features being analyzed are independent of each other

> A naive Bayes classifier is a simple probabilistic classifier based on applying Bayes' theorem with strong (naive) independence assumptions. A more descriptive term for the underlying probability model would be "independent feature model".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

Comment: got the empirical naive bayes classifier part, thanks. How does this differ from parametric bayes classifier?